# Clean linq implementation to filter a list by grandchildren

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of Users whom are attached to applications that included clients. I'm looking to filter a list of users by the application and client via Linq and am spinning.

Ideally I'd be using a single statement where Application.Name == "example" that are also in ClientApp.Id == 1.

This is where I'm at thus far but am having some internal brain issues regarding nesting. Any help is appreciated

```
var users2 = users.Where(x => x.App.Select(y => y.Name).Contains("example"));

public class User
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public List<Application> App { get; set; }
}
public class Application
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<ClientApp> Client { get; set; }
}
public class ClientApp
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use nested calls to `Enumerable.Any` to filter this:

```
var filtered = users.Where(u => 
                   u.App.Any(
                      a => a.Name == "example" 
                        && a.Client.Any(c => c.Id == 1)));
```